# Multiple IPs are not getting bind in mongodb conf file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I am trying to bind multiple IP to mongodb config file, one is `0.0.0.0` and other is `127.0.0.1`. I did the following change in configuration file

> /etc/mongod.conf

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: "0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1"
```

Than I reloaded the configuration by the following command

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Than checked if the server is listening on localhost as well or not by the following command.

```
netstat -tlpn
```

It shows the output only for `0.0.0.0`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Why is it not listening to localhost as well?

Comment: The [IP address `0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) means all IP v4 addresses (which includes `127.0.0.1`). You could achieve the same outcome by not specifying any `bindIp` address, as "bind to all IP addresses" is the default behaviour as at MongoDB 3.2. Have you tried connecting to `mongod` via localhost, and if so was there any error? What are you trying to achieve with multiple IP addresses? The `bindIp` configuration determines what IP address(es) `mongod` listens on if your server has multiple addresses, but you still need to configure appropriate firewall settings.

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue and the thing is everywhere it's written that you have to bind them like this

bindIp : 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.50

but that doesn't work.

The MongoDB version 3.2.x have the following configuration and its working for me.

```
    bindIp : [127.0.0.1,192.168.0.50]

    example :

# network interfaces
net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp : [127.0.0.1,10.12.2.1,10.12.65.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The IP addresses and/or full Unix domain socket paths on which mongod should listen for client connections. You may attach mongod to any interface. To bind to multiple addresses, enter a list of comma-separated values.

```
EXAMPLE
localhost,/tmp/mongod.sock
```

**WARNING:** Before you bind to other ip addresses, consider [enabling access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#checklist-auth) and other security measures listed in [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) to prevent unauthorized access.

Note: Starting in **MongoDB 3.6**, mongod bind to **localhost (127.0.0.1)** by default. See  [Default Bind to Localhost](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#bind-to-localhost).

To bind to all `IPv4` addresses, enter `0.0.0.0`.

To bind to all `IPv4` and `IPv6` addresses, enter 0.0.0.0,:: or alternatively, use the `net.bindIpAll` setting.

**Note :** `--bind_ip` and `--bind_ip_all` are `mutually exclusive`. That is, you can specify one or the other, but not both.